# Screencast Keys enabled but invisible

Tags: screencast

I have followed tutorials to install and enable screencast keys, and I can see that it is technically "functional" but the actual icons and words are invisible? In the screenshot below you can see I have opened the menu and ticked the enablement box at the top, but there are no icons or text displaying regardless of which keys I press. To show what I mean regarding it functioning, but not correctly, I have turned on the background setting to a light colour with the actual colour set to black. As you can see in the bottom left, the field is showing up, but the actual icons and text are not there.

I'm currently on Blender 3.2 using Screencast Keys version 3.10. Please let me know if anyone knows how to help!

[image]